# How to set density(no. of particles per area) of hair particles with weight paint?

Tags: particles, weight-painting, hair

[image]I want to create a fade hair style but using weight paint affects the length of the hair not the actual density.

Comment: In the vertex groups for particles you can choose if they affect density, length, clump and other settings.

Comment: @cegaton it's working for length but not for density.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your weight paint or particles. Please add images that will help us understand what you have done so far. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.